# Representation of domain of complex curves.

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to complex analysis.I would like to know how are ranges of complwx functions represented in graph theoritically.I know that domain of the complex values are reprented in complex plane.I would like to know how the ranges of those functions represented.

Comment: Could you be more specific? A curve in the complex plane is a continuous map $I\rightarrow\mathbb C$ where $I$ is an interval or $I=\mathbb R$

Comment: I would like to know how to plot mapping of complex function.